# To build 3d editor with OpenGL and Qt which methods/shell I use?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I want to build simple 3d editor , using OpenGL and Qt.
First what is the correct way to approach  such project ? to follow this example :
http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-labs/wolfenqt/
or this is more newer and better way :
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-widgets-opengl.html
I will use the latest Qt . 
Where to start ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should more care about than which toolkit to use, are the data structures you're going to manage your models with. Also such mundane things like picking are to be considered.

How about you take a look how other 3D modelers do it? The source code of Blender-2.5x is full of beautiful ideas.

Comment: Also for more game specific one - check GtkRadiant, QTRadiant or DarkRadiant

Comment: yeah i know about the data structures thing , i just want to know which method to use when working with Qt